# Two processes have different behavior while running with the same command and same binary file

Tags: ffmpeg, process

There's an app in Ubuntu server, which runs a FFMPEG instance. That instance keeps working fine.

But when I run the same command with the same binary executable in terminal, it exits after 3 or 4 minutes with log 'Conversion failed!'.

Both processes are run as root user, and also using same `.so` libraries.

I also viewed environment variables of the correct process with `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/62243/environ`:

```
LANG=en_US
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
SHELL=/bin/sh
INVOCATION_ID=89a8c6c4b24d4a1b919e0cf529366876
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:308
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/_MEIDvDVDH
AV_LOG_FORCE_COLOR=
AV_LOG_FORCE_256COLOR=
```

I created a shell script to set environment variables before my command:

```
export var1=value
export var2=value
export var3=value
.
.
.
my_command_here
```

Still problem exists.

I can't find out why. And it's become a headache.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The runtime environments differ. Compare `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Comment: These are env variables for the correct process, and I set them to run my command: LANG=en_US
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
SHELL=/bin/sh
INVOCATION_ID=89a8c6c4b24d4a1b919e0cf529366876
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:308
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/_MEIDvDVDH
AV_LOG_FORCE_COLOR=
AV_LOG_FORCE_256COLOR=

Comment: @waltinator Even by setting those variables before running my command, still same thing happens. Can you please help me with this? I'm stuck

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks. Edited the question. Anything helpful?

Comment: `(var1=value; var2=value; my_command_here)` doesn't do anything useful unless `var1` and `var2` were previously exported. Use `var1=value var2=value my_command_here` or `(export var1=value var2=value; my_command_here)`

Comment: @muru Thanks. Tried with `var1=value var2=value my_command_here` and logged env variables of my process. It showed completely different result than what I mentioned in question. Why aren't they set?

Comment: You mean `var1` and `var2` aren't set in `/proc/<pid>/environ`? You should check if `my_command_here` is function, alias or shell script which modifies the environment

Comment: @muru I edited the question. Created a shell script to set values before running the command. Then I checked and they're set. Still problem exists. Can you help please?

Comment: Have you tried cutting off access to the terminal? Redirect stderr and stdout to some file and close stdin or redirect `/dev/null` to stdin?

Comment: @muru ffmpeg has an option `-nostdin` which I believe blocks stdin. And also you can set `-loglevel panic` which then it logs nothing. And I used those options. If you mean something else please tell me.

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote.